# custom ListView doesn't refresh

Tags: android, listview, refresh, android-fragmentactivity

I have a problem with a `ListView` on android. Is not really a `ListView`, because it's implemented on a Sherlock `Fragment`. So in particular:
I have 2 classes, one is the `Fragment`, and one is a normal `Activity`. The `Activity` downloads one file from the web, and in the `Fragment` there is a list with the downloaded files.
This is my adapter for the `Fragment`:

```
File mydownload = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Sample Folder");
int i = 0;
while ( i < mydownload.list().length) {
    adapter.add(mydownload.list()[i]);
    i++;
}
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

So the adapter catches all the files in the Sample Folder and put it on the list. When I download a file, the adapter doesn't refresh the list (I think because it is in a different context, but I don't know the solution for that). To refresh I have to close and open the application. I tried a lot of possible solution but nothing helped.

edit: my `Fragment` code:

```
public class AppleFragment extends SherlockListFragment{    
/** An array of items to display in ArrayList */
private static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null; 


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    /** Creating array adapter to set data in listview */

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.liststyle, new ArrayList<String>());
    View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    /** Setting the array adapter to the listview */
    File mydownload = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Gazzetta Ufficiale");
    int i = 0;
    while ( i < mydownload.list().length) {
        adapter.add(mydownload.list()[i]);
        i++;
    }
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return v;

}    

@Override
public void onStart() {     
    super.onStart();
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id){
            String gazza = (String) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
            File pdf = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Gazzetta Ufficiale" + "/" + gazza);
            try {
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdf);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }   
    });

    /** Setting the multiselect choice mode for the listview */
    //getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() { 

        public boolean onItemLongClick (AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id){
            final int pos = position;
            String gazza = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
            final File pdf = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Gazzetta Ufficiale" + "/" + gazza);
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which){
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        //Yes button clicked
                        pdf.delete();
                        adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(pos));
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        //No button clicked
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setMessage("Vuoi eliminare la Gazzetta?").setPositiveButton("Elimina", dialogClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Annulla", dialogClickListener).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}   
}
```

Download activity:

```
private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
        try {
            File mydownload = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Gazzetta Ufficiale");

            if (!mydownload.exists()){
                mydownload.mkdir();
            }

            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);     

            String url = sUrl[0];
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            }
               request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
                        DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                        .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
                        .setTitle("Gazzetta " + sUrl[1])
                        .setDescription(sUrl [2] + ". In download..")
                        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/Gazzetta Ufficiale", sUrl[1] + ".pdf");

            manager.enqueue(request);


        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        toast = Toast.makeText(Gazzetta_detail.this, "Download in corso...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tryed to call the notifyDataSetChanged() method on the adapter after you fetch new datas?

Comment: I fetch the new datas in the activity, how can i call this metod for the adapter on the fragment? Sorry but is the first application for me!

Comment: Ok I'm not very familiar with fragments but I'll try to help you anyway. I suppose you are calling a function to update your listview from the activity, right? In that case you can still call the method I suggested you at the end of the update function, inside of it like : adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: I edit the question, look my whole code for the 2 classes

Comment: I'm a bit confused.. You call an AsyncTask an activity, this is actually wrong.I still believe that your are triggering the update of your list only at startup of the application with onCreateView(). To make thing easier just add a button inside your layout that just call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and see if something happens, if so that means that after you fetch the data you are not triggering properly the update on the adapter or you are not updating your list with the new datas.

Comment: Oh sorry i put here only a part of the activity, wihtout on create etc etc..however, i'll try!

Answer (score 0):

Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your Adapter.

Some additional specifics on how/when to call notifyDataSetChanged() can be viewed in this
[Google I/O video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&t=17m38s).